# IP address range for BigCommerce hosting?

Tags: security, bigcommerce

I would like to secure my servers for incoming traffic from BigCommerce.

BigCommerce allows for configuring a [3rd party email server](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Email-in-BigCommerce#third-party) 
as well as [webhooks](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/webhooks/about-webhooks). What are the addresses that will be used by these services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't guarantee that webhooks will be sent from a specific block of IPs--those addresses can change any time and without notice. But if the purpose is to confirm that incoming webhooks are coming from BigCommerce, you can specify custom headers when creating your webhook. The headers are returned in the webhook payload, so you could set the custom header to a basic auth username/password, and check that at runtime to authenticate the POST.

We do have a list of IPs that I can send you for the SMTP server. Happy to connect by email if your contact info is still the same!

Comment: Thanks Karen. I sent an email to what I believe is your work email. I grabbed a list of IPs from the _spf.bigcommerce.com TXT record.

Comment: Hi Karen, this post is 4 years old.  Is it still the case BigC can't guarantee the webhooks will be sent from a specific block of IPs?  Thanks.

Comment: @dlink Karen no longer works for Big Commerce. https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/community?language=en_US is your best bet.

Comment: @dlink when I implemented this, I used the headers - https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/integrations/webhooks#security.
Regardless of where the source traffic was coming from, I could authenticate the call, and make sure it was an authorized caller.

Comment: Thanks, JJS.  Problem is we have ports 80 and 443 shut down in the firewall.  will need to check for authentication in the header on a separate box that calls in through the firewall.  Thanks DL